# Unable to Pass Data Into DB Using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to save some data into db using AJAX.It says it's successfully done but nothing happens.No data is being saved.Just keeps saying "Success".

**index.php** // form

```
<div id="cont">
<div id="kayit" style="display:none;">
Success
</div>
<div id="basarisiz" style="display:none;">
Empty or Fail
</div>
<form method="post" id="yaz" onsubmit="return false">
<input type="text" name="title" id="baslik" placeholder="Başlık" required><br/>
<textarea name="content" ></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="gonder" value="Gönder" id="gonder" onclick="kayit()">
</form>
```

**yaz.js**

```
function kayit()
{
var baslik = $("input[name=title]").val();
var icerik = $("input[name=content]").val();
if (baslik =="" || icerik == "")
{
$('#basarisiz').show(1);
$('#kayit').hide(1);
}else
{
$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "yazikaydet.php",
data: $("#yaz").serialize(),
success: function (sonuc) {
if (sonuc == "hata") {
alert ("unable to connect to db");
}else {
$('#kayit').show(1);
$('#basarisiz').hide(1);
$("input[name=title]").val("");
$("input[name=content]").val("");
}
}
}) }}
```

**yazikaydet.php** //the file which will save the data,not processing

```
<?php 
include 'giris.php'; //sessions and connection strings
if(isset($_POST["gonder"]))
{
    $baslik = $_POST["title"];
    $icerik = $_POST["content"];
    $tarih = date("d/m/20y");
    $kull = $_SESSION["username"];
    $kaydet = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO gonderiler (yazar,tarih,baslik,icerik) VALUES ('$kull','$tarih','$baslik','$icerik')");
    if($kaydet)
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to escape data before using it in a query, try printing `mysqli_error()` to see if there are any errors

Comment: This condition seems to be not correct. if (sonuc == "hata")

Comment: @RavinderReddy You might be right,Im trying to learn AJAX ,can you clear the code up for me please?

Comment: In yazikaydet.php file you are echoing "Yes" or "No" based on the condition, but in ajax success code you are checking with "hata" which seems to be not correct.